# Center text not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `span` with text, and a `div` wrapping it. I'm trying to center the text in the `span`. I tried using `flexbox` to center it, but it's not working. It's centered horizontally but not vertically. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

(The only reason `span` is there, is so I can center the text. If I can center the text without using the `span`, then I won't use it.)

#### JSFiddle

```css
#headerScrollDown {
  font-size: 85px;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerScrollDown"><span>&#155;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `&#155;` character of the monospace font is not vertically aligned, so you need to play with the dimensions a bit to make it work.

Check this example:

```css
#headerScrollDown {
  font-size: 85px;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#headerScrollDown span {
  line-height: 75px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerScrollDown"><span>&#155;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jessica, Will appreciate a voteup as well :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Center text working, Try replace Arrow icon with X. It's ideal in The middle. The problem is with this icon.

Comment: Your'e right! So how can I get the char to center correctly?

Comment: I don't know how to do that with this specific char.  Try use font awesome icon "angle-right", but maybe you don't want using external solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the font being used. On a Mac, the default monospace font is Courier, which has a slight offset. Try changing the font to get a more uniform result. The CSS will only work uniformly for the same font.

For example, for Courier, you can add

```
span{ transform: translateY(-9%); }
```

to the span and get it vertically centered. Using px to adjust the margin-top will not be uniform for all font-sizes.

My ultimate suggestion is to explicitly define the font-family as default fonts can change depending on OS.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define a height for vertical arrangement. Then you must find a balance between line height and font size of text.

```css
#headerScrollDown {
  font-size: 85px;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#headerScrollDown > span {
    height: 54px;
    line-height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerScrollDown"><span>&#155;</span>
</div>
```

You can see the difference is easier to: https://jsfiddle.net/mz77dnk5/